# Git getting snaphot from master in single commit

Tags: git, visual-studio, push, rebase

I have a problem in Visual Studio. I am working in one branch, and I need a new snapshot of master to merge into my local branch (git pull or rebase). But when I do `git pull origin master` I have several commits in outgoing window, waiting to be pushed along with commit from my local branch.
I need clean push, including only changes I made in local branch but not other commits picked up from master after pull/rebase.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you really want to do. What are your branches? Is there only master branch or are there any other branches locally? Can you share your commit history including origin/master and your local branch(s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this is your commit history:

```
A - B - C(master, origin/master)
 \ 
  D - E - F(xy)
```

Then, you did some work on `master` branch:

```
A - B - C(origin/master) - G - H(master)
 \ 
  D - E - F(xy)
```

And you wanted to rebase your `xy` branch onto the `master` branch:

```
A - B - C(origin/master) - G - H(master)
                                \ 
                                 D - E - F(xy)
```

In this scenario, if you want to push `xy` branch to remote repository before pushing to `master` branch, you will see `G - H - D - E - F` commits will be pushed, **because remote repository doesn't have any knowledge about `G - H` commits**.

If you don't want to see `G - H` commits in the commit list, first you have to push `master`, then push `xy` branch to `origin`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am asking

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I have master branch and one "xy" local branch. When I work sometime in this branch (XY) I want to pull changes from master into local XY branch, before I push my work. But when i rebase my local XY branch on top of master, then I have all commits made in master into my local branch and if I want to push my work from XY local branch I see all commits (merged from master))in otgoing window in VS. I dont want all commit pulled from master to be in my outgoing.